# Is there any C API to check if the source IP address is from same network?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have a server written in C. Is there any API or way to check if the incoming request is from same network as the server is running in ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about linux platform.
I do not think there is an API for that.

I see 3 methods to check what you need:

**1)** You can use ttl of ping to see whether client is too many hops away thus most likely being not a member of your network. 
Just try this as a proof of concept

```
ping -t 1 8.8.8.8
```

**2)** Also you can get mac address of client's IP from arp table and compare it with mac of your gateway. if they match then *there is a chance* that your client does not belong to your network.

**3)** Also you can enumerate all ip addresses you bind to and apply theirs masks to your ip and client ip and check for the match. If they match then client certainly belong to your network.